# Login via POST method returns a 403 error

Tags: authentication-authorization, 10

I have enabled the Rest and the Basic Auth core modules on a Drupal 10 site, but I am unable to log in using the following code. I keep getting a 403 error.

```php
$drupalUsername = 'myuser';
$drupalPassword = 'mypass';
$drupalApiEndpoint = 'https://mysite.com/user/2'; // Replace with the correct user ID
    
$authHeader = 'Basic Authentication ' . base64_encode($drupalUsername . ':' . $drupalPassword);
    
$ch = curl_init($drupalApiEndpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [$authHeader]);
  
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
    
echo $response;
```

Do you have any hint?

PS

Got it working with two small changes!!!

```
$drupalApiEndpoint = 'https://mysite.com/user/2?_format=json'; // Replace with the correct user ID

$authHeader = 'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($drupalUsername . ':' . $drupalPassword);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two changes necessary in the code:

- The endpoint should be `'https://mysite.com/user/login?_format=json'`
- <del>The headers should include the *Accept* one, which must be set to
  `'application/json'`</del> (*****)

If, without being logged in, you try to access a user profile page, which is what happens when the request is for https://mysite.com/user/2, you would get either:

- a 403 error, if anonymous users are not allowed to access user profiles (The *View user information* permission is not given to anonymous users.)
- the user profile, if anonymous users are allowed to access user profiles (The *View user information* permission is given to anonymous users too.)

Drupal will not redirect from https://mysite.com/user/2 to https://mysite.com/user/login. That would eventually happen when the requested page is https://mysite.com/user.

(*****) - Earlier Drupal 8 versions used the *Accept* header, but that was latter changed (starting from Drupal 8.0.0-beta12). See [Accept header based routing got replaced by a query parameter](https://www.drupal.org/node/2501221).

Comment: thx got it working in the end. so ysite.com/user/2  was the actual user that tried to log in! Also had to change Basic Authorization to authHeader = 'Authorization: Basic

Comment: PS2 it looks like there is no need for a separate login at /user/login with basic auth